# how move img via arrow key jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to move an IMG via an arrow key using jQuery. I do not know how to use a method on a document. I do not know whether or not to use parentheses at the end of the method in the switch statement.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                function moveIMG(event) {
                    var x = event.keyCode;
                    switch(x) {
                        case 37:
                            doLeft;
                            break;
                        case 38:
                            doTop;
                            break;
                        case 39:
                            doRight;
                            break;
                        case 40:
                            doBottom;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                function doTop() {
                    $("div").animate({top: '+=100px'},1200);
                }
                function doBottom() {
                    $("div").animate({bottom: '+=100px'},1200);
                }
                function doLeft() {
                    $("div").animate({left: '+=100px'},1200);
                }
                function doRight() {
                    $("div").animate({right: '+=100px'},1200);
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onkeydown="myFunction(event)">
        <div id="animateimg" style="position:absolute"><img src="black.png"></div>
        <script>$(document).moveIMG()</script> <!-- I think in this place the problem -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `moveIMG` is not a jQuery.fn method, which is how you are trying to use it.  It's just a global function.  However, to bind on an event on the document you do it just like any other event binding.  `$(document).on(eventName, eventHandler)`

Comment: Also, to call a function in JavaScript, you must use parentheses, like as follows: `doTop();`

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
$(document).on("keydown", moveIMG)
```

and add missing parens like `doLeft();`

```js
function moveIMG(event) {
  var x = event.which; // use which instead in jQuery
  
  switch (x) {
    case 37:
      doLeft(); // Add parens
      break;
    case 38:
      doTop();
      break;
    case 39:
      doRight();
      break;
    case 40:
      doBottom();
      break;
  }
}

function doTop() {
  $("div").animate({
    top: '+=100px'
  }, 1200);
}

function doBottom() {
  $("div").animate({
    bottom: '+=100px'
  }, 1200);
}

function doLeft() {
  $("div").animate({
    left: '+=100px'
  }, 1200);
}

function doRight() {
  $("div").animate({
    right: '+=100px'
  }, 1200);
}


$(document).on("keydown", moveIMG);
```

```html
<div id="animateimg" style="position:absolute">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/000">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Switch is a mess.

Since from a personal preference I don't like `switch` statements here's my suggestion. By using a predefined Object literal to store your moves mapped to a *keyCode* integer:

```js
var keyMoves = {
  37: {left: '-=100px'},
  38: {top:  '-=100px'},
  39: {left: '+=100px'},
  40: {top:  '+=100px'},
};

function moveIMG (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();                             
  $('div').stop().animate(keyMoves[ev.which], 1200);
}

$(document).on('keydown', moveIMG);
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50/000"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/
https://api.jquery.com/stop/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap your function inside a live listener (`on`) to catch all live events. Also use parenthesis when calling a function.

```
$(document).on("keydown",function(e) {
            var x = e.keyCode;
            switch(x) {
                case 37:
                    doLeft();
                    break;
                case 38:
                    doTop();
                    break;
                case 39:
                    doRight();
                    break;
                case 40:
                    doBottom();
                    break;
            }
        })
```

Comment: This does not properly call the functions, need those parentheses for the function calls.

Comment: Thank you @Alec I didnt notice this case as the main question was about configuring a listener.

Answer (score 1):

to capture the arrow keys you need `keydown` event on `document :

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left
        doLeft();
        break;

        case 38: // up
        doTop();
        break;

        case 39: // right
        doRight();
        break;

        case 40: // down
        doBottom();
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```